# Pelleting bacterial cells using centrifugation and getting proteins in the supernatant

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, microbiology, cell-membrane, cell-culture

Do significant amount of proteins from cells find their way in supernatant during pelleting? If the answer is yes then I see two ways in which protein can be in the supernatant
.

1) Through lysis during pelleting
2) Through leakage of protein from cells during pelleting

if significant amount of lysis occur during pelleting then obviously protein will be there in the supernatant due to lysis alone. However, If most cells (like 98%-99%) remain intact  then only by leakage significant amount of protein can be in the supernatant. Both way can also contribute. Which is the case?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but secreted proteins will be in the supernatant.

Comment: @canadianer I know. But here I am interested in the protein that are inside the cell and are forced outside so to speak by the process of pelleting.

Comment: Have you actually seen intracellular proteins in the supernatant after centrifugation that weren't there before?

Comment: @canadianer No. Someone suggested that possibility.